# Storing array in firebase / querying multiple strings in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to query multiple strings in firebase, or store an array to firebase database?

I would like to get the string value of the different nodes. Here is my structure:

```
msg {
  msg1: "some string"
  msg2: "another string"
  msg3: "yet another"
}
```

I would like to get the value of the 3 messages, how do I achieve this? I am new to firebase databasing.

Comment: is your database structure like that or that just an example ? thanks . Also, can you post an image of your Database?

Answer (score 0):

To save multiple strings at one node you can use a Map:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("msg1","some string");
map.put("msg2","another string");
map.put("msg3","yet another");
yourRef.setValue(map);
```

To retrieve this data all together you can do it this way, create a pojo:

```
public class DataPojo {
    //Make sure this variables types match exactly your firebase variable names
    private String msg1;
    private String msg2;
    private String msg3;

    public DataPojo() {
        
    }


    public String getMsg1() {
        return msg1;
    }

    public void setMsg1(String msg1) {
        this.msg1 = msg1;
    }

    public String getMsg2() {
        return msg2;
    }

    public void setMsg2(String msg2) {
        this.msg2 = msg2;
    }

    public String getMsg3() {
        return msg3;
    }

    public void setMsg3(String msg3) {
        this.msg3 = msg3;
    }

    
    
}
```

And then retrieve any message like this

```
yourRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   DataPojo dp = snapshot.getValue(DataPojo.class);
   String msg1  = dp.getMsg1();
   String msg2 = dp.getMsg2();
   String msg3 = dp.getMsg3();

}

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

yourRef is where you want to post your data and from where you want to retrieve it. It's created this way:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: What if the no. of msg nodes in my database is indefinite? Can I create an arraylist and use dataSnapshopt.getChildren then put all of it in the arraylist?